# Error in URL configuration trying to set up django-contact-form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have installed the `django-contact-form` module and modified my `urls.py` file at the root level of my django app to contain:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url


urlpatterns = [
    # ... other URL patterns for your site ...
    url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls')),
]
```

as per the instructions listed here:

https://django-contact-form.readthedocs.io/en/1.2/quickstart.html

But when I try and run my Django app, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

I haven't added 'contact_form' to the INSTALLED_APPS setting as the guide explains that is not necessary.

Does anyone know what might be happening? Without that line in my urls.py file, the app runs fine.

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.sites` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @gglasses this worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `django.contrib.sites` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py`?